# Inline derivative macro

Tags: macros, loops

I'm trying to define a macro so that `$\D{x^2,y^3}$` expands to `$\partial_x^2 \partial_y^3$`.

I tried

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\D}[1]{%
    \@for\@token:={#1}\do{\partial_\@token }
}
\makeatother
```

but I get

```
Missig { inserted
Missig } inserted
```

Comment: `didn't work' is no precise diagnosis

Answer (score 1):

`\@...` named macros require the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair unless being defined in `.sty` or `.cls` files.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\Der}[1]{%
  \@for\@token:={#1}\do{\partial_\@token}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\Der{x^2,y^3,z^{17}}$
\vskip2\baselineskip
$\Der{{x_1}^2,y^3}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that I am using \makeatletter and \makeatother but it doesn't work. Maybe the problem is when I have things like `$\D{{x_1}^2}$`

Comment: @hello: Yes, you forgot to provide a compilable document :-*(, but `$\D{{x_1}^2}$` works for me too

Comment: Yes sorry for that, I will do next time. The error I get is "Missing { inserted."

Comment: I made a mistake, it doesn't work with `$\D{{x_1}}$` because it gives a double subscript error. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: @hello: No, I can't help because I don't get that error!

Comment: Even the `$\D{{x_1}}$` one? I get it with your minimal working example. So a derivative of order one with a variable that has a subscript

Comment: @hello: Ah that one -- yes, but that's another issue, actually